# Как передать данные неявной активности через putExtra()?

Tags: java, android, activity

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблема. Необходимо передать адрес(строку) другой активности неявно, причем именно через putExtra(). Пробовал сделать так :

```
            Uri address = Uri.parse("http://google.by");

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.putExtra("uri", address);

            startActivity(intent);
```

Принять и отобразить так :

```
    String uri = getIntent().getStringExtra("uri");
    webView.loadUrl(uri);
```

Так же добавил для активности с браузером разрешения :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>        

    <activity android:label="TestBrowser" android:name="WebActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Но в списке приложений нет данного приложения. Может что посоветуете?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам надо ещё добавить вот это в интент-фильтр вашей активити в манифесте

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил. Проще сделать так

```
        Uri address = Uri.parse("http://google.by");

        Intent intent = new Intent("your_custom_id");
        intent.putExtra("uri", address);

        startActivity(intent);
```

И в манифесте поменять на

```
 <activity android:label="TestBrowser" android:name="WebActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your_custom_id"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```